# How to change the UTC Time

Tags: c#

I have developed my application in c#. In this application OPC Server returns the UTC Time automatically. But the issue is I want to change this UTC Time same as System Time. (The difference between System Time & UTC Time is 5.30)

Comment: So you want to return local time instead of UTC?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [DateTime.ToLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

First check if the Kind property is DateTimeKind.Utc then [`toLocalTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx)
 would be enough else you will have to use `AddHours` and `AddMinutes`